# How to embed instagram post on a blog post

Tags: 2013, blog

I can manage to post a Instagram photo on a SharePoint page, but on a blog post it's different. I get the message "This HTML cannot be insterted because this type of content is not allowed".

I added instagram.com to the HTML field security settings just in case, but it makes no difference. Am I missing something? I am using SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Simpler way, just use this web part, no code/ no registration/ no tokens needed. https://github.com/thenikhilk/sharepoint-instagram-feed ![TheNikhilK SharePoint Instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4nnV.png)

Answer (score 2):

Sharepoint blog posts does not allow to put any `<iframe>` tag, every time you try to put an iframe element inside a post you will get the same message. This is what I did to put an iframe in a post:

Open your post´s page and once in there open the **edition mode**, add a **Script Editor** webpart, add:

```
<html>
  <!--Add your iframe element-->
  <!--You need to notice that any element that you add in the edition mode will be visible in ALL your other posts, that's why you need to add a "display: none" to maintain it hidden-->
  <iframe src="Your_instagram_photo_URL" id="iframe_name" style="display:none"></iframe>
</html>

<!--now add some JS to show the iframe only in the post that you need-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var myPost = window.location.href;
    if(myPost === "your_sharepoint_post_URL"){ //paste the URL of the post where you want the iframe to be visible
      $("#iframe_name").show();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Now you just will need to add some CSS to adjust your iframe position, use "**position: absolute**" so you can move it all around the page.